# Excel Conditional Formatting in Text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet, that shows different delivery dates inside one column. I would love to use conditional formatting to highlight dates that are close to today's date. Is that possible with conditional formatting?

The data would look like this:

```
D / E344103 LT 05.04.22 / E350521 LT 25.03.22 / E316524 LT 31.05.22 / E316601 LT 15.04.22 / E318314 LT 24.03.22
```

I would love to have everything farther out than 4 Days coloured in red, and as we're approaching closer to today's date move to orange and then finally green.

Any help that gets me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

I have no idea how to approach this. I have very limited experience with conditional formatting.

Comment: Could you add in which range the data is located, e.g. `A1:A6` or `A1:F1`? Also, to be accurate, if today is 3/22/2022 which is the first date to include? You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71583354/edit) at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate column with just the dates

The next step would be to find the difference in dates. There is a help forum on this here. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-8235e7c9-b430-44ca-9425-46100a162f38

From there you can highlight all cells that meet this criterion
If you need a more step by step approach let me know

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying "No": conditional formatting is only applicable on the whole cell, so conditional formatting on a part of a cell is impossible.

Therefore, I would advise you to split your information into different cells. In case this is possible, you might use conditional formatting for that matter.

In case you can't split your content over different cells, you might be forced to use VBA for this matter, as you can see from this simple result screenshot:

[image]

The corresponding VBA code is very basic:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Today is 23/03/2022."
ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=10, Length:=10).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```